# How to programmatically associate a taxonomy term to a field

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to import user profiles data from a JSON file. Several fields are *entity reference* to *vocabularies*. 
I'm able to create a new taxonomy term entity in the universities vocabulary bundle using the following code:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => "University of Bologna", 
  'vid' => 'universities',
])->save();
```

Now I have to link this newly created term to a field contained in *Profile Type*. I'm testing the following code.

```
    $values = array(
        'type' => 'profile_type',
        'uid' => 3043,
    );
    $profileStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('profile');
    $profileEntity = $profileStorage->create($values);
    $profileEntity->field_entry_university->appendItem($term);
    $profileEntity->save();
```

However, this approach doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EntityInterface::save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Asave/9.0.x) returns the status of the save operation, not the entity:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => "University of Bologna", 
  'vid' => 'universities',
])->save();
```

`$term` is always [1](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/constant/SAVED_NEW/9.0.x).

So first assign the newly created entity to `$term` and then save it:

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => "University of Bologna", 
  'vid' => 'universities',
]);
$term->save();
```

Adding the entity should be no problem then:

```
$profileEntity->field_entry_university->appendItem($term);
```

It doesn't matter whether you add the target entity or the target ID.

Answer (score 1):

`appendItem` takes an array.

Try `$profileEntity->field_entry_university->appendItem(['target_id' => $term->id());`

Comment: I've edited the code accordingly: it adds the term to the vocabulary, but it doesn't link it to the field.

Comment: Is `$profileEntity->save()` called?